# Win32 textbox control alt keypress message

Tags: winapi, unicode, keyboard, editbox

I need to hookup alt+alphanumberic keypress inside a child window control.

I have written this program to test it's functionality. But it seems it does not response to keystrokes 
like ALT+X , ALT+X which are necessary for my application(keyboard translator).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif

/* glaobal variables */
HWND hwndEdit = NULL;
HWND hwndWindow = NULL;
WCHAR* lpszClassName  = L"Vijesekara Keyboard Test Application";
WCHAR* lpszAppName = L"Vijesekara Keyboard Test Application";
int main_window_width = 0;
int main_window_height = 0;
WNDPROC edit_old_wndproc;

/*
  GWL_WNDPROC
*/
#ifndef GWL_WNDPROC 
#define GWL_WNDPROC (-4)
#endif

/* child window ID's */
#ifndef __CHILD_WINDOW_EDIT_ID__
#define __CHILD_WINDOW_EDIT_ID__
#define ID_EDIT     2000
// :TODO: more comes from here //
#endif 


/* constrains on child window positions */
#ifndef __CHILD_WINDOW_POSITION__
#define __CHILD_WINDOW_POSITION__
#define EDIT_CHILD_LEFT_PRECENTAGE 0.05
#define EDIT_CHILD_RIGHT_PRECENTAGE 0.05
#define EDIT_CHILD_TOP_PRECENTAGE 0.10
#define EDIT_CHILD_BOTTOM_PRECENTAGE 0.10
// :TODO: Other controls //
#endif

/* main window procedure */
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
/* edit box procedure */
LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc(HWND ,UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM );

/* resize child windows */
void ResizeChildWindows();

/* win main entry */
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{

  WNDCLASS wndclass;

  wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW |CS_VREDRAW ;
  wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wndclass.hInstance = hInstance ;
  wndclass.hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
  wndclass.hCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
  wndclass.hbrBackground =(HBRUSH) GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
  wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
  wndclass.lpszClassName = lpszClassName ;

  /* Register class */
  int result ;
  result = RegisterClass( &wndclass) ;

  /* if failed to register window */
  if ( 0 == result )
  {
    MessageBox(NULL,L"Registering Window Have Been Failed" , lpszAppName, MB_OK);
    exit(0);  
  }

  /* Create the window */
  hwndWindow = CreateWindow(lpszAppName , lpszAppName ,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,\
                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
  if(NULL == hwndWindow )
  {
    MessageBox(NULL,L"Window Creation have being failed", lpszAppName,MB_OK);
    exit(0); 
  }              
  ShowWindow(hwndWindow, iCmdShow);

  /* Enter message loop */
  MSG msg ;
  while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL, 0,0 ))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
  } 
  return msg.wParam;
}

/* window procedure */
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(message)
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
     if( hwndEdit != NULL)
     {
        MessageBox(NULL,L"Edit control handle have already initialized",lpszAppName , MB_OK);
        exit(0);
     } 
     hwndEdit = CreateWindow( L"edit" ,NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL\
                              |WS_BORDER|ES_LEFT|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,0,0,0,0,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_EDIT\
                              ,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
     if( NULL == hwndEdit )
     {
       MessageBox(hwnd, L"Edit child window control creation failed", lpszAppName, MB_OK);
       exit(0);
     }   

    edit_old_wndproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwndEdit,GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)EditBoxProc );
      break;

    case WM_SIZE:
       main_window_height = HIWORD(lParam);
       main_window_width = LOWORD (lParam);
       ResizeChildWindows();
       return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:

      /*:TODO:process */
      break; 

    case WM_DESTROY:

       PostQuitMessage(0);
       return 0; 
    default:
      return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}

/* resize window procedure */
void ResizeChildWindows()
{
  MoveWindow(hwndEdit,main_window_width*EDIT_CHILD_LEFT_PRECENTAGE , main_window_height* EDIT_CHILD_TOP_PRECENTAGE , \
    main_window_width * (1- EDIT_CHILD_LEFT_PRECENTAGE - EDIT_CHILD_RIGHT_PRECENTAGE)          ,// height 
    main_window_height * (1- EDIT_CHILD_TOP_PRECENTAGE - EDIT_CHILD_BOTTOM_PRECENTAGE), TRUE   // width 
 );  
}
static int alt=0;
static int ctl=0;
static int sys =0;
WCHAR buffer[1024];

LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch ( message)
  {

    case WM_SYSCHAR:
      sys =1;
      if( lParam && (1<<29) ) { alt= 1;}
      else { 
        alt=0;
      }

    case WM_KEYPRESS:
      wsprintf( buffer,TEXT("KeyCode is :%d"), wParam);
      MessageBox( NULL,buffer, TEXT("Vijesekara Keyboard"), MB_OK);
      SetFocus(hwnd);
      /* keyboard procedure */


    alt =0;
    if ( sys==1)
    {
      sys=0;
      break;
      }

    return 0;

    default:
      break;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(edit_old_wndproc ,hwndEdit,message,wParam,
           lParam);
}


// end of vijesekara_keyboard.cpp
```

Note: Inside the subclassed  textbox , the WM_CHAR message is not working for the alt keystrokes, I it does
not sent a WM_CHAR message with alt key pressed to the for AlT+keystokes.So I log all the messages using spy++
and then I found WM_SYSCHAR have been sent instead of WM_CHAR for those messages inside a editbox child
window.

Any idea how could I do this?

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: If someone presses ALT+X you get WM_SYSCHAR instead of WM_CHAR.  So handle WM_SYSCHAR.  What's the problem?

Comment: No I get WM_SYSCHAR when I press ALT+C like other character, It don't work for Alt+A Alt+X like few keys. Does my question is not clear? I'll try to improve it, meantime try to edit it if you willing.

Comment: I ran your sample code once I'd fixed problems like WM_KEYPRESS not existing.  I get WM_SYSCHAR for ALT+C, ALT+A and ALT+X.  Do you get this problem in your sample code, or in another application?  If another application, does it have menus or accelerators or shortcut keys that are swallowing the ALT+X?

Comment: No,I'm talking about the same application, 
You mean it does shows that messagebox with keycode?

Comment: Yes.  I commented out the `case WM_KEYPRESS:` line.  I initialised the WNDCLASS structure because there was something wrong with it: `memset(&wndclass, 0, sizeof(wndclass));`.  And I get a message box for ALT+C, ALT+A and ALT+X.

Comment: let me have the source that you modified, you may post it as a answer. I'll accept it. and next we need to find out what had happened there.

Comment: Seriously, after the declaration of wndclass I initialise it as described above.  And I commented out WM_KEYPRESS.  That's it.  The code is otherwise identical.  If you still aren't getting WM_SYSCHAR for ALT+A then run spy++, and see what messages you are getting and what's handling them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is pretty strange,
This is my spy+ output for the Alt+A key.

[image]

So then I have hook the WM_SYSKEYUP message, and the Fixup is this,

```
case WM_SYSKEYUP:
  if( lParam && (1<<29) ) {alt=1;}else{break;}
  if( wParam == 'A' || wParam=='Z'|| wParam =='X' || wParam== 'W' || wParam == 'Y' ){}else{break;}

case WM_SYSCHAR:
  sys =1;
  if( lParam && (1<<29) ) { alt=1; }
  else { 
    alt=0;
    break;
  }

 case WM_CHAR:
  wsprintf( buffer,TEXT("KeyCode is :%d"), wParam);
  MessageBox( NULL,buffer, TEXT("Vijesekara Keyboard"), MB_OK);
  SetFocus(hwnd);
  /* keyboard procedure */


  alt =0;


  return 0;
```

And also when I break (calling the default window procedure) on WM_SYSKEYU it gives a nasty ding-dong sound
inside the Windows.I have return it then that sound disappear.

What arx claim is very strange. And Yes I have mistaken WM_KEYPRESS, there's no something called WM_KEYPRESS.
And It should be corrected to WM_CHAR. According to him without these chances MessageBox appears. That's
pretty strange. @Arx, you could please post your answer, so somebody else who digging it may benefit, and also
I could give you some credits too. And also dig why was that happened and after that we could accept that
and this answer would keep as an alternative answer (does not address the question, but have fixed the
application).

Comment: please note that this does not answer the question, but this will fix the issue. for the benifit of somebody who found the same bug.